# NovaCode DocX document page count

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

Is there any way to get number of pages from Novacode Docx document?
So far I found a lot of properties none of which is page count.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you intend to do, but one way is via the paragraph object:

```
para.Append("Page ").AppendPageNumber(PageNumberFormat.normal);
para.Append(" | ").AppendPageCount(PageNumberFormat.normal);
```

Comment: This works. i've used it. Don't know why this is not an accepted answer!